# How to clear local client minimongo data upon changing route?

Tags: meteor

I'm implementing infinite scrolling on two separate pages (by setting Session limit for publications) - let's call it Page I and Page II. Each page has its own subscription, both published from the same collection but with different subsets of data. Suppose page I is receiving these documents in the following order:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F....
```

and page II is receiving:

```
E, B, G, H, K...
```

Some of the items will appear on both pages, these would be `E, B, G` in this example. Now the problem is once I visited page II and return to page I, the order of the items on page I is now changed to:

```
E, B, G, A, C, D...
```

As you can see, all common items (E, B, G) will now show up first on the list in the order as shown above, even though the data from publication was already sorted before from the server. I've tried fixing it by sorting it again from client in helpers with `.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 } }, {limit: limit})` and that seems to fix the issue but for some reason it also breaks all infinite scroll.

I'm trying to understand what causes this and I suspect that it's because the common documents were cached in client local minimongo from the page before it. I also tried stopping subscription by assigning a handle to it and then used `.stop()` on it but that didn't clear the data.

I'm new to Meteor. Could someone advise me a method to effectively clear all local client data upon changing route?

Comment: Can you add you're publication and subscription code. It's really hard to figure out what's going on without code...

Comment: After digging through previous posts on here, I discovered someone else had this exact same problem and it was simply a case of syntax issue. The "limit" argument in my code above should have been positioned like this: `.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: limit})`. I fixed that and everything is behaving the way it should now. I've also learned that it doesn't matter if we already sorted the data on server when publishing, we still need to sort it again on client when we subscribe to that piece of data.